# How do you host a Node server from your computer so everyone can connect to it

Tags: node.js

I've made a node program and I want to host it trough my computer, how can I go about doing so. Currently I'm using "require("net");" function to start the server locally!

```
var net = require("net");
var server = net.createServer();

server.on("connection", function(socket){
   //Stuff happens in here
});
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 6969, function(){
    console.log("Server is listening to %j",server.address());
});
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal working example of your code?

Comment: @TelmoTrooper update the post

Comment: If you `node myServer.js` (or whatever the name is), then it is running, right? Or do you mean accessible from another computer on your network? Accessible from the internet and running all the time?

Comment: Just to clarify, is your question about how can you host a Node.js web application in your computer so other people can access it?

Comment: @TelmoTrooper yes, sorry realized i worded the question weirdly

Comment: @crashmstr i meant it so it's accessible to the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a Node.js application you have to install Node.js - you can download it [HERE](https://nodejs.org/en/). Then in the command line / terminal, you navigate to the location of your code, and run Node.js with your file as an argument:

```
cd /c/some/location/with/your/file
node file.js
```

There is now a Node.js process that is listening on your chosen port - so it's hosted locally.

Looking at the Node.js documentation for [Server.listen](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen), it looks like the app is already listening for outside connections. The signature (or one of the signatures) is `server.listen(PORT, HOST);`. And I also see:

> If host is omitted, the server will accept connections on the unspecified IPv6 address (::) when IPv6 is available, or the unspecified IPv4 address (0.0.0.0) otherwise.

So your app should already be contactable from the outside (although you may have to open the port explicitly depending on firewall rules). So some other computer, if they make a TCP/or whatever request to `<the IP address of your computer>:6969` then the server will respond.

I'm actually surprised that the default host is `0.0.0.0` and not the loopback address (`localhost` or `127.0.0.1` - these are the same address).

Comment: i've probably worded my question wrong. I want to open my node program to the world. Currently it's just running on localhost

Comment: Oh i see. I'll adjust my answer above

Answer (score 1):

Note not my answer look it up here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/271824/node-js-is-not-accessible-from-external-ips-on-ubuntu

You cant access node.js from outsiede because it is listening on localhost (127.0.0.1). You need to configure it to listen on 0.0.0.0, with this it will be able to accept connections on all the IPs of your machine.

`server.listen({
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 6969
});`

Comment: This is the default behavior of `server.listen`

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, you want to host your node app with your computer as a web server. It's pretty easy you can follow this [blog](https://afteracademy.com/blog/how-to-convert-your-laptop-desktop-into-a-server-and-host-internet-accessible-website-on-it-part-2-cdb4b3633fa9).

Basically the steps include:

- Getting a Domain name.
- Registering your IP with DNS so that your
  domain name points to your computer when someone enters that in the
  browser.
- Running the web server (Node) to handle the requests.

> Note: You might face some problems if your ISP(Internet Service
>   Provider) changes your IP address frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Since you clarified your question is about how can you host your application so other people can use it, it's not really Node-specific.

You have to open the appropriate ports in your system-level firewall and in your router as well (search for your router's model and you'll see it). Web applications always run in port 80 (for HTTP) and port 443 (for HTTPS), both in TCP. Do note that some providers won't allow you to host a server in port 80, so you'll have to try it out to check if that's the case for you.

Your Node application seems to be running in port 6969, so you either set it to use port 80 (which requires admin privileges) or use a reverse proxy to send all traffic to/from port 80 to port 6969. You can do that with [nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/), for example.